# Entity Framework ( Entity travelled from EntityObject to DTO and then again to EntityObject ) is it possible to easily update it in db at this point?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework

i think my whole questions is inside title bar =]
but i'll explain little more.

i've got 2 related tables in database ( Customers and Orders )
and wcf service which returns Customer and all related Orders as DTO's
like this :

> class CustomerDto
>   {
>   int ID;
>   IList< OrderDto > Orders;
>   }
>   and : 
>   class OrderDto
>   {
>   int ID;
>   string someString;
>   }

what is happening:
client asks for customer (customer is returned with orders ), makes some changes (adds/removes orders, changes someString), and sent data back to service.

here i wanted to ask, is it possible to attach modified Customer to database context,
or i'll need make changes manually?

Thank You !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an [article with downloadable code sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc700340.aspx) on using EF and WCF together, including updates. You can also look at [RIA services](http://download.microsoft.com/download/F/B/8/FB8CA635-296B-487F-965C-8148F08B5319/riaservicesoverviewpreview.pdf).

Comment: hi. thx for reply.
jea that approach in link that you gave works when you dont use dto's ( i think objects are returned with objectstatemanager )
but when you get dto you dont have any ObjectStateManager attached.